# How do i make username input in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I just wanted to make a cmd script that has a username option
like this output

Please write your username:
Example

Hello Example

I have searched a little but all i got nothing they made it with macros
Thanks.

Comment: `set /?`. Take a special look to the `/p` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
@echo off
set /p user=Enter username: 
echo Hello %user% !
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set /p UName=Enter Name
```

**NB:** Do not use USERNAME as the variable as it is a system variable. See

```
set u
```

Comment: Thanks about the information, I did not notice that!